# Handling variables with data from another sheet on google drive calc

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Drive Calc File,

Google says in their web help [how to reference data from another sheet](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75943&topic=1361471&ctx=topic), but what happens if what I need is to make the reference depending on my fields on the new sheet?

Ok, let me explain further... Let's say I have a sheet named 'My Data' and a Sheet named 'My List'. And on 'My List' I have a column where I'll place a number (let's say column A)

- On Column A value: 15
- On Column B value: 'My Data'

On column C of the same sheet instead of

> ='My Data'!B15

I want to have something like

> ='My Data'!B@ColumnA

Where @ColumnA is the number on column A. If it's possible, I have interest of doing this:

> =@ColumnB!B@ColumnA

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `INDIRECT()`.

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!" & A1)
```

I'm assuming that the values are in row 1 and that the value in Row B is surrounded by single quotes. Otherwise, you'll have to put them in.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!" & A1)
```

The `&` concatenates the values. You could use the function `CONCATENATE()` instead.

[I put spaces for readability, but they're not needed.]